# Create Google Charts with code

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

Im looking to load a number of google charts depending on the data selected from my database. (The number of charts will be different depending on the selection)

I can load a single chart with the following code, but I'm struggling to load multiple charts via looping through a list

My intention is to have no charts drawn until a selection is made and data passed to the code below for each item in my list. There could be over 20 charts!

Help much appreciated, I use `C#` but only just getting to `php` and `html`

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});     
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          
        function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "getJSONdata.php",
              dataType: "json",
              async: false
              }).responseText;

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          var options = {
                    title: 'BMU',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 300,
                    series: {
                        0: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1 },
                        1: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1},
                         2: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1}},
                    hAxis: {
                        textStyle:{fontSize: 10},
                        format: 'HH:mm',
                        },
                    vAxis: {
                        textStyle:{fontSize: 10},
                    }, 
                    chartArea: {backgroundColor: '#fffff0'},


                    };
          var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="float: left; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: looks like an old example, `async: false` has been deprecated -- where is the list you need to loop?

Comment: At this stage I'm looking to query the database using php to get a list of IDs and pass them to the getJSONdata.php where tha database call is for the chart data.  getJSONdata.php is currently hard coded for one ID and works fine where one chart is produced. I was thinking of looping from the body area. I tried to generate serveral charts of the same chart with a button but got nowhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could setup similar to following...

```
// load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: getList,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

// load id list
function getList() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getList.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (listData) {

    // draw chart for each id
    listData.forEach(function (itemId) {
      drawChart(itemId);
    });

  }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
    console.log(text + ': ' + errMsg);
  });
}

// draw id chart
function drawChart(itemId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getJSONdata.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      id: itemId
    }
  }).done(function (jsonData) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
      title: 'BMU',
      width: 500,
      height: 300,
      series: {
        0: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1 },
        1: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1},
        2: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1}},
      hAxis: {
        textStyle:{fontSize: 10},
        format: 'HH:mm',
      },
      vAxis: {
        textStyle:{fontSize: 10},
      },
      chartArea: {backgroundColor: '#fffff0'},
    };

    // create new div for chart
    var container = document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
    console.log(text + ': ' + errMsg);
  });
}
```

Comment: that's working fine now. Just need to sort out adding values to the parms in the following call

Comment: that's working fine now. Just need to sort out running the code after  adding the coal value  to the following call "url = 'getList.php?fuel=coal' from a button click

Comment: that url should work but it is also what the `data` key is for, instead of adding to the url, you can set data --> `data: {fuel: 'coal'}`

Comment: Ok will try that